# Move pads separately in altium

Tags: altium

Is it possible to move individual pads of a component separately ? Since diodes and resisters has long legs, they can go over.

[image]

Comment: I made an edit to make this question easier to find for people who might have the same problem in the future. If I made a mistake and this isn't what you meant to ask, feel free to roll back my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want to edit the footprint and make it so the diode must be bent to a larger pitch.. yes, it's possible. Simply double-click on the footprint and unlock primitives:

[image]

I think you're better off to make different footprints and select the appropriate one for the job though. For example, you might make diode footprints with 10, 12, 14 mm pitch.

Answer (score 2):

Select the component and un-check the 'Lock Primitives' box in the component properties.
You can then move individual bits and pieces of the component footprint by themselves.
Don't forget to re-check the box when you're done ...